# Cascade types in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, cascade, jpa-2.1

Given two entities `Department` and `Employee` forming a one-to-many relationship from `Department` to `Employee`.

<sub>Since the relationship is quite intuitive, I am leaving out the entity classes.</sub>

In `Department` :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>(0);
```

In `Employee` :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Department department;
```

Please notice that I have nowhere mentioned `cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}` though the following relationships are merged on both the sides (owning and inverse sides).

```
Employee employee = entityManager.find(Employee.class, 18L);
employee.setEmployeeName("zz");

Department department = employee.getDepartment();
employee.setDepartment(department);

department.setDepartmentName("e");
department.setLocation("e");

entityManager.merge(employee);
```

While merging `Employee`, `Department` is also merged.

Inversely, in this following case,

```
Department department = entityManager.find(Department.class, 1L);
List<Employee> employeeList = department.getEmployeeList();

for(Employee e:employeeList) {
    if(e.getEmployeeId().equals(27L)) {
        e.setEmployeeName("xxx");
    }
}

// No further EntityManager operation(s) here.
```

New values set to an `Employee` instance are directly merged into the associated underlying database.

From [OpenJPA](http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/trunk/docbook/manual/jpa_overview_meta_field.html#jpa_overview_meta_cascade) :

> `CascadeType.MERGE`: When merging entity state, also merge the entities
>   held in this field.

From [EclipseLink Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Relationship_Mappings/Collection_Mappings/OneToMany) :

> MERGE – If the owning entity is merged, the merge is cascaded to the
>   target of the association.

From [JPA Wiki Book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Cascading) :

> `MERGE` - Cascaded the `EntityManager.merge()` operation. If `merge()`
>   is called on the parent, then the child will also be merged. This
>   should normally be used for dependent relationships. Note that this
>   only affects the cascading of the merge, the relationship reference
>   itself will always be merged. This can be a major issue if you use
>   transient variables to limit serialization, you may need to manually
>   merge, or reset `transient` relationships in this case. Some JPA
>   providers provide additional merge operations.

Regarding the test cases above, I do not precisely understand when exactly `cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}` is needed or useful. What is the use of `cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}` in this case?

How do those test cases merge `Department` and `Employee` respectively without using `cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}`?

I am currently on EclipseLink 2.6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is a fundamental feature of JPA: every change made to a managed entity is **automatically** saved to the database. No need to call `merge()` or anything else. You open a transaction, get entities, and modify them, then commit the transaction, and that's all you need to modify the database.

`merge()` is used to copy changes from a **detached** entity to its **managed** counterpart.

Comment: I see the absence of `cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}` makes no  different then. When exactly is it needed?

Comment: It makes a difference when you actually merge a **detached** entity. If you have a detached department containing detached employees, and you merge the department, the employees will also be merged or not depending on the persence of the cascade.